# How can I display different size of image from a .map function?

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying some images of planets with a `.map` function, but I don't know how to change their size (different size for each) so I have a key "size" in each object with values like "6px".

I've tried like that :

```
  const SolarSystem = () => {
  return (
    <div className="solar-system-container" style={{display:"flex"}}>
      {Planets.map((planet) => (
        <Planet style={{width:planet.size}} name={planet.name} image={planet.image} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also tried to put the size here :

```
<img style={{width:size}} src={image} alt={name} onClick={openModal} />
```

(in the return of the variable) it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on the implementation of `<Planet />`. If its a custom component, React wont know on what DOM element to apply the `styles` object. Please share its implementation :)

Comment: Please edit the question and add the `Planet` Component. I'll post the answer accordingly

Comment: Can you share a [CodeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) of this implementation? It will be easier for others to help, then

Comment: Welcome to the community, please accept the answer if it solved your issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a size parameter with the planet.size value and use it in your component.

`const SolarSystem = () => { ...  <Planet size={planet.size} name={planet.name} image={planet.image} />`

`<img style={{width:size}}src={image} alt={name} onClick={openModal} />`

Comment: It worked ! Thank you

Comment: Can you mark it as the solution please : )